# Changing ListBox ItemsSource property while item is selected results in IndexOutOfRange Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

If I change the `ItemsSource` property of a `ListBox` while an item is selected I get IndexOutOfRange exception because `SelectedIndex` property is set when an item is selected. If no item is selected in the `ListBox` exception is not raised but even if I set the `SelectedItem` property to null before changing the `ItemsSource` the exception still occurs if an item was selected because `SelectedIndex` property still has a value.

Is there a solution or a workaround for this problem?

Edit: Here is the sample code because this problem only occurs if I apply a `Contains` filter in my LINQ to objects expression AND an item is selected in the ListBox... MyList is a `List<>` of CLR objects...

```
lstMyList.ItemsSource = MyList.Where(i => i.TypeId == 1);
```

That works fine. This modified LINQ query also works fine (if no item is selected) but if an item is selected I get `IndexOutOfRangeException`

```
lstMyList.ItemsSource = MyList.Where(i => i.TypeId == 1 && i.DisplayName.Contains(someString));
```

If I redirect this LINQ query to a var or a list of CLR objects the query works fine but when I try to make it an ItemsSource of my ListBox I get the exception (even if I make this var or a list of CLR object ItemsSource of my ListBox instead).

Comment: Could you write the exception trace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `SelectedIndex` to -1

---

EDIT: OK, try that instead:

```
listBox.ClearValue(Selector.SelectedIndexProperty);
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work, I get IndexOutOfRange exception on that line... The funny thing is that as long as an item is not selected SelectedIndex = -1 doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: That also generates IndexOutOfRangeException.